# Variable not working after if statement

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, parameter-passing

This is my current code,

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];    
CGRect *FullViewRect = NULL;
if (screenRect.size.height == 568.0f) // iPhone 5
   {CGRect FullViewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);}
else
   {CGRect FullViewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);}

UILabel *Count3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: FullViewRect];
Count3.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:Count3];
```

But Count3 is not visible?
No errors are given but FullViewRect has no value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it fails is your `if` and `else` statements each declare a *new* `FullViewRect`, which hides the one you actually want to change. Modify your code to be this:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];    
CGRect FullViewRect;
if (screenRect.size.height == 568.0f) // iPhone 5
   {FullViewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);}
else
   {FullViewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);}

UILabel *Count3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: FullViewRect];
Count3.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:Count3];
```

Comment: Thanks; fixed. I took for granted that the OP was getting code to build... bad on my end I guess.

Comment: I'm scared that people with this much (much? oh the irony) knowledge of C are trying to "program" "applications"...

Comment: (And, by the way, now `CGRect FullViewRect = NULL;` doesn't compile. Just leave that poor variable uninitialized, it will be initialized anyway :) )

Comment: I know what you mean... last week I cut my finger and did pretty good fixing it with a bandage. Tomorrow I perform my first open heart surgery; wish me (and the patient) luck! :P

Comment: Oh poor guy :( Good luck, I'll pray both for you!

Answer (score 5):

I'm wondering how this compiled. It shouldn't.

```
UILabel *Count3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: FullViewRect];
```

This is wrong, since `FullViewRect` is a `CGRect *`, but the method expects a `CGRect`. (Why do you assume things instead of reading the documentation?)

Furthermore, you are re-declaring that variable inside the branches of the `if` statement. Your code needs to be (with the variable names fixed to begin with a lowercase letter):

```
CGRect fullViewRect;
if (screenRect.size.height == 568.0f) {
    fullViewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
} else {
    fullViewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
}
```

But, this is something overly basic. You should be learning C and no trying to make iOS aplications yet if you don't understand this.

One further error is this:

```
if (screenRect.size.height == 568.0f)
```

***Never*** try to compare floating-point numbers like this, because they aren't exact. Use something like this instead:

```
if (screenRect.size.height > 500.0f)
```

or similar.